# jQuery | AJAX | JSON Form Submit, error not firing. What am I missing?

Tags: jquery, html, json, forms

I'm back with the same form I've been struggling with... My issue is that I can get this form to submit correctly, but the error response doesn't work. I see that the response is coming back in the console with an error, but it's not displaying my error message in my response... I can submit empty and my jQuery displays as though it's successful, even when my response is: `{"status":"error","message":"Name is blank"}` or `{"status":"error","message":"Email is blank or invalid"}`

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="span6">
<h4>Ask us anything or request a quote:</h4>
<div id="form" style="padding-top: 1em;">
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post">
<div class="controls">
<input class="span6" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="What is your name?" required>
</div>
<div class="controls">
<input class="span6" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="What is your email address?" required>
</div>
<div class="controls">
<textarea rows="3" class="span6" name="message" id="message" placeholder="How can we help you?"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="controls">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="formSubmit" id="formSubmit" value="Send E-Mail">
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="thanks" style="display:none">
<h3>Thank you for that! <br>
<span class="muted"><small>We appreciate you getting in touch with us...</small></span></h3>
<p>We'll try to get back to you as soon as possible. We know your time is valuable, so we'll try as hard as we can not to waste it.</p>
</div>
<div id="error" style="display: none;">
<h3>Error <span class="muted"> Something in that message did not work right...</span></h3>
<p>Please <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="restForm">CLICK HERE TO RESET THE FORM</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formSubmit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/contact.php",
            data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

                success: function(msg){
                $("#form").fadeOut('fast');
                $("#thanks").fadeIn('slow');
                $('#contactForm').get(0).reset();
                $('form[name=contactForm]').get(0).reset();                 
                },
                error: function(){
                $("#form").fadeOut('fast');
                $("#error").fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the PHP:

```
function checkEmail($email){

if(eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$]", $email)){
    return FALSE;
}

list($Username, $Domain) = split("@",$email);

if(@getmxrr($Domain, $MXHost)){
    return TRUE;

} else {
    if(@fsockopen($Domain, 25, $errno, $errstr, 30)){
        return TRUE;
    } else {

        return FALSE;
    }
}
}   

$response_array = array();

if(empty($_POST['name'])){

//set the response
$response_array['status'] = 'error';
$response_array['message'] = 'Name is blank';

} elseif(!checkEmail($_POST['email'])) {

//set the response
$response_array['status'] = 'error';
$response_array['message'] = 'Email is blank or invalid';

} else {

//send the email
$body = $_POST['name'] . " sent you a message\n";
$body .= "Details:\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
mail($_POST['email'], "SUBJECT LINE", $body);

//set the response
$response_array['status'] = 'success';
$response_array['message'] = 'Email sent!';

}

echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Comment: Small reminder. If any of the answers were helpful to you, please upvote them and if one was the most helpful, please mark it as the best answer. It encourages people to answer questions and helps others evaluate the answers when they search and find this question. It also makes it more likely that people will answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem confused about what jQuery considers an AJAX "error". You're returning an item that says "error" within it does not make it an error as far as jQuery is concerned. It's an error if the call is to a URL that gives a 404 or 500 error (for example, you point it to the wrong server or there is no service at that URL).

As long as a request is made and a response is successfully retrieved, jQuery is happy that it helped you and will pass the result to the "success" method. You need to look at the result within your success and see whether the JSON says it worked or not. If so, then update the display appropriately and if not then update it to show the error message.

Only expect the error method to be triggered when there is an actual failure to make the AJAX call to the server and get a response. Other examples of things that could trigger that would be a timeout or an attempt to call a server other than the one which served up this page. Expect success to get the results every other time.

Given what you've said above about the format of your responses:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/contact.php",
    data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      if (msg.status == "error") {
        // If we got an error message back in the JSON, replace our generic error
        // message with the more specific error the server sent.
        $("#form").fadeOut('fast');
        if (msg.message) {
          $("#errorMessage").html(msg.message);
        }
        $("#error").fadeIn('slow');
      } else {
        // The call succeeded.
        $("#form").fadeOut('fast');
        $("#thanks").fadeIn('slow');
        $('#contactForm').get(0).reset();
        $('form[name=contactForm]').get(0).reset();
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      $("#form").fadeOut('fast');
      $("#error").fadeIn('slow');
    }
  });
```

Pair that with a slight change to your HTML (notice that I put a selector on the span with the error message):

```
<div id="thanks" style="display:none">
<h3>Thank you for that! <br>
<span class="muted"><small>We appreciate you getting in touch with us...</small></span></h3>
<p>We'll try to get back to you as soon as possible. We know your time is valuable, so we'll try as hard as we can not to waste it.</p>
</div>
<div id="error" style="display: none;">
<h3>Error <span id="errorMessage" class="muted">Something in that message did not work right...</span></h3>
<p>Please <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="restForm">CLICK HERE TO RESET THE FORM</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, so the error here would be no response or an actual error (as you've described).What I need to do in this case I need to analyze the response for 'error' and then tell jQuery to react appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use something like the jQuery validate plugin. This will validate your forms before they are submitted which is an altogether better way of doing things as it cuts down the amount of requests you are making to the server to process the PHP.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Comment: It's great to do client side validation to avoid making users wait to get error responses to things you could tell them about before they submit. I'm all for it. But it doesn't change the need to do a full set of validation on the server side to make sure that someone didn't step around your client side validation or to validate things which are not as easily validated client side (is the user name unique, is that coupon code valid, is the gift certificate one which has been already redeemed). So server side validation and errors are still needed even if you add that.

Comment: I appreciate that. I will validate with jQuery validate, but I want to make sure my backend validation works correctly as well.

Comment: If you validate on the client side though (at least the basic stuff) then you will ultimately reduce the amount of validation required on the backend therefore making a more efficient application. Just a thought :-)

Comment: I will be validating on the front side, right now, however, I'm trying to figure out my PHP and backend validation... I know the front end validation works just fine. I need to make sure my responses are correct and that my jQuery works. It's a two step process. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnMunsch Of course server side validation is also required but generally this should only be the application logic (checking usernames etc. as you mention). Things like checking Email addresses are the correct format and stuff like that (general housekeeping validation) should be done on the client side before it's sent through to the server. (Basically I think we are both getting at the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are expecting the Ajax to "error" when you send back json that just happens to have status=error in it.

What you really should do is set a http status code error that will trigger the error handler.

Comment: status "error"
message "Email is blank or invalid"

This is my actual JSON... it seems to be coming back with the correct response, no?

Comment: Yes the content of your ajax request has the word error in it, but that is not what triggers jQuery's ajax handler to fire the error event. It fires the event when a HTTP error is returned.

Comment: Try adding `header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);` to your php code when you have an error any it will act like you are wanting it to